# How do we use less than one unit of a multi-component soap pod?

Tags: cleaning, kitchen

It is no longer possible to find stores here that sell dishwasher detergent as just a box of powder or a bottle of liquid; they only sell these "pods" that are supposedly "one size fits all". As a result, dishes are occasionally coming out of the dishwasher with white evaporation stains on them, suggesting the soap-to-filth ratio is too high (it only happens when there's not a lot of thick gunk to clean). It's easy enough to remove the stains, but it would be nice to figure out how to stop them in the first place.

The obvious answer is to use less than one unit of a detergent pod. But this seems really difficult at first glance, as each pod contains one chunk of powder and multiple chunks of variously-coloured gels. I presume that none of these should be mixed before they're ready to be used (though if they can be, that would be nice, as that would suggest being able to liquify several together and dispense as needed across several days). If it was just a single chunk of powder it'd be no issue (just cut it in half or something).

Answer (score 2):

First make sure your dishwasher is working correctly. Using too much detergent *can* leave deposits, but the measured amount of detergent in those pods is based on the typical amount of *water* used by a dishwasher, not the "soap-to-filth" ratio.

[Troubleshooting dishwasher residue](http://smallnotebook.org/2012/02/02/5-tips-to-improve-your-dishwasher/)

That aside, you *can* certainly cut a pod into sections and use a fraction of the contents or make a liquid out of it. Keeping them conspicuously separate until use is mostly marketing. The capsule is made of [polyvinyl alcohol](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/269wfn/what_is_the_plastic_wrap_on_dishwasher_detergent/) (PVA), which is simply a water soluble polymer that dissolves in the presence of water, so everything is dispersed at once when the cycle runs anyway. Many liquid dishwasher detergents already mix the rinse agents and water softeners into their products, so making your own liquid from the contents of a pod should not be a problem.

Keep in mind that these pre-measured pods are more expensive than their liquid and powder counterparts, so since you are dispensing with the convenience factor, you should try looking for alternative sources for the bottled product.

[Buy your dishwasher detergent online](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=shop&q=dishwasher+detergent)

or perhaps you can

[Make your own homemade dishwasher detergent](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=homemade+dishwasher+detergent).

No pods required.